# Typo3 4.5 Admin and user settings show blank page

Tags: typo3

I use typo3 4.5.3 in a shared  hosting without allow_url_fopen support. So see blank page in the backend. Putting php.ini file in some folders fixed backend problem but in the backend menu when i click the top "admin" link, or left user settings link, and configuration, db check links i see blank pages on the right part without any error. Have you ever seen this problem?

Comment: Please read http://dmitry-dulepov.com/article/blank-empty-page-in-typo3.html, then report, what error appears in your error log.

Comment: i've already done displayerrors and devipmask issue but still see no errors and just blank page. I will make a fresh installation without php.ini allow_url_fopen option.

Comment: So have you had a look at your PHP log? That's where fatal errors end up.. In general, I suggest to consult the typo3 mailing lists (typo3-english, see http://lists.typo3.org) instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: No php logs in my shared hosting. I can't see in cpanel. Thanks i will write to the typo3 mailing list.

Comment: At last i fixed. I put php.ini file with allow_url_fopen on option into: for user settings:typo3/sysext/setup/mod folder, for configuration module:typo3/sysext/lowlevel/config folder, for page module:typo3/sysext/cms/layout folder and continue for the other modules...

Comment: @levent, you can answer your question and mark your own answer as accepted. This way, your question will disappear from the "unanswered questions" results.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered. It blocks the list of unanswered questions